# Keyboard Not working Properly

Tags: macos, keyboard, imac

I have an old iMac on MacOS 10.13 High Sierra with the standard Magic Keyboard (before the current MK2). I normally use the iMac in Target Display mode, and then use Screen Sharing from my newer iMac to connect to it when I need to do something directly on the old machine. Naturally, I use the newer keyboard attached to my newer iMac.

A few days ago, I found that most of the keys on the old iMac appear not to be working. After a lot of testing, I can say the following:

- The old keyboard connected to the newer iMac works well
- An alternative Bluetooth keyboard connected to the old iMac also has the same problem
- An alternative *Wired* keyboard connected to the old iMac also has the same problem
- Everything is fine when I enter using the newer iMac keyboard on screen sharing
- I have ensured that mouse keys and slow keys are turned off

All this suggest that there is a software problem.

I had it working for a while. I then restarted, and it worked for a while longer. Now it’s gone back to the problematic behaviour, and I can only type the `a` key, for some reason.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what os x is on it ?

Comment: MacOS 10.13 High Sierra. It won’t support Mojave.

Comment: did you try to refresh the driver on iMAC for the Magic keyboard ? also I suggest you run the EtreCheck and see what is says.

Comment: when you connect the alternate wired/BT keyboards, do you *disconnect* (i.e. turn off) the old keyboard?

Comment: @Allan I have now. Same thing …

Comment: Next thing...boot into Safe Mode or Recovery and see if the problem still exists with the *wired* keyboard.

Comment: @Allan Thanks for your suggestion. I booted into Safe Mode, and both the wireless and the wired keyboard are OK. Normal mode, the problem appears again …

Comment: Now you've gotten somewhere - you know BT and USB work and the HID kexts are good as well as keyboard layouts.  This comes down to something that's being loaded.  The next test is to create another user (can do this in safe mode), then boot normally and log into that account.  This will narrow it down to an account specific or system wide issue.

Comment: @Allan I already tried that. I created another user (not in safe mode) to see whether account-specific files might be the culprit. The keyboard didn’t work there either.

Comment: Your next step is to do a fresh install.  If you want to test it prior to actually wiping your disk, install to a external USB (flash disk is fine).  You just need 16GB of space.  If everything works while booting off that image, go for the reinstall (make a backup first, of course)

Comment: @Allan Thanks again. I am interstate for a few days, so I will do as you suggest when I get back. There’s nothing on the machine I can’t easily reinstall, so that might do the trick. I’ll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to your investigative work, it appears that the common problem is the Bluetooth on iMac.

Try resetting you BT.

You will loose paring so you have to pair it again.

To reset BT hold `Shit+Option` and click on the BT icon in the menu bar.

Now you will see the Debug menu.

Comment: This is really weird. I reset Blutooth and removed all of the devices. I then reconnected the keyboard which involved typing in a 6-digit number. After that, the keyboard doesn’t work again, including the numbers I just typed in. Only the letter `a`. The same applies to a 3rd-party bluetooth keyboard. I can enter the number for pairing, but only the `a` works after that.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have also tried a _wired_ keyboard and get the same problem, so it’s not bluetooth. Still have no idea.